# Switching two activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to Android apps development. I have a question on switching two activities. I followed a youtube for switching two activities: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wz0bM-xy3M

But when I enter those code as shown in the bottom for my next class `NextActivity.java`,

I noticed that I have three mistakes.......

1. `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` - The method `onCreate(Bundle)` of type `NextActivity` must override or implement a supertype method
2. `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`-The method `onCreate()` in the type Application is not applicable for the arguments (Bundle)
3. `setContentView(R.layout.next)` - The method `setContentView(int)` is undefined for the type NextActivity

What's mistakes do I make? Thanks a lot!

```
package gorilla3d.activitytutorial;


import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class NextActivity extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend Activity instead  of Application

```
...
public class NextActivity extends Activity {
...
```

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer if you think it is helpful.